# Compile error in Wai installing Yesod on OS X

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I'm pretty new to Haskell, and trying to install Yesod with Cabal, but I'm running into this compilation error:

```
cabal install yesod --force-reinstalls


Network/Wai/Parse.hs:106:61:
    No instance for (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.MonadThrow
                       (ConduitM S8.ByteString Void IO))
      arising from a use of `allocate'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.MonadThrow
         (ConduitM S8.ByteString Void IO))
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `allocate
         (do { tempDir <- getTmpDir;
               openBinaryTempFile tempDir pattern })
         (\ (_, h) -> hClose h)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      (key, (fp, h)) <- flip runInternalState internalState
                        $ allocate
                            (do { tempDir <- getTmpDir;
                                  openBinaryTempFile tempDir pattern })
                            (\ (_, h) -> hClose h)
    In the expression:
      do { (key, (fp, h)) <- flip runInternalState internalState
                             $ allocate
                                 (do { tempDir <- getTmpDir;
                                       openBinaryTempFile tempDir pattern })
                                 (\ (_, h) -> hClose h);
           _ <- runInternalState (register $ removeFile fp) internalState;
           CB.sinkHandle h;
           lift $ release key;
           .... }
Failed to install wai-extra-2.0.2
```

[This is the full output when installing](https://gist.github.com/MaxGabriel/8477623)

I'm using the latest Haskell Platform with the `ghc-clang-wrapper` script.

Cabal versions:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

GHC version:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Some of the tutorials mention using a cabal sandbox, but my version of cabal (1.16) is too old  for that. If the sandbox is likely too help I'll try and get that working (had a little trouble updating cabal to 1.18).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have several modules which when installed beside existing modules cause name collisions. Further up in the output before the error you posted there are a bunch of errors like this:

```
Network/HTTP/Client/Conduit.hs:37:9:
   Ambiguous occurrence `MonadResource'
   It could refer to either `Data.Conduit.MonadResource',
    imported from `Data.Conduit' at Network/HTTP/Client/Conduit.hs:13:1-19
    (and originally defined in `resourcet-0.4.10:Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal')
   or `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadResource',
    imported from `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource' at Network/HTTP/Client/Conduit.hs:15:1-35
    (and originally defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal')
```

These may be caused by `--force-reinstalls`.  This is basically what `cabal sandbox` was created for so it may be easier to post a question about whatever is going wrong in updating that.  You should be able to `cabal install cabal-install` to update it to the newest version.

Edit:

If `cabal install cabal-install` is working then the first thing I would check, as Chrules mentions, is where your path is pointed at.  When you install cabal via cabal it will get put in `~/.cabal/bin` so that needs to be first in your path.  If you do `which cabal` you'l probably now see something like `/usr/bin/cabal`, you want that to be `~/.cabal/bin/cabal`.  Since you're local user packages are now messed up anway here's what I would do.

```
rm -rf ~/.cabal ~/.ghc # This deletes everything you installed with cabal
cabal update # Reinitialize the platform cabal
cabal install cabal-install # Update cabal
cabal install yesod # This will work since you nuked your ~/.cabal and ~/.ghc
```

After doing this you will have nothing installed but yesod, and you probably want `yesod-bin` as well since that has the `yesod` binary (at `~/.cabal/bin`).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Updating `cabal` gives a success message ("Installed cabal-install-1.18.0.2"), but `which cabal`/`cabal --version` still finds the old version. This sounds easy to fix so I'll figure that out tonight and try `cabal sandbox`.

Comment: You'd want ~/.cabal/bin to be first in your path. You're probably hitting your distro's yesod from /usr/bin or something like that, so when it updates, the old version still gets picked first.